Simple basic qiskit example program
I have wrote a simple program in qiskit
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, Aer
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerSimulator

# Create a simple quantum circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.h(0)
qc.measure_all()

# Simulate the circuit
simulator = AerSimulator()
tqc = transpile(qc, simulator)
result = simulator.run(tqc, shots=1024).result()

# Print the result
print(result.get_counts())

My System Information:

Mac OS
Python - 3.9

And i get the following error.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, Aer
ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit' 


Since qiskit version 0.46.0, the execute function is deprecated. See here and here. I suppose you need to replace result = execute(qc, backend, shots=1024).result() by result = backend.run(qc, shots=1024).result() and remove the import of execute.

@upe i have changed the code and i am getting another error please help me. I have updated the code.

for questions purely concerning programming please ask on StackOverflow with tag qiskit

Try this:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer

# Create a simple quantum circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.h(0)
qc.measure_all()

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

# Simulate the circuit
result = backend.run(qc, shots=1024).result()

# Print the result
print(result.get_counts())
```


thank you......

The Aer simulator is no longer part of the Qiskit package.
You now need to install Qiskit Aer separately by executing in your terminal:
pip install qiskit-aer
You can then import the Aer Simulator:
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator 

For more info, you can just follow the Qiskit Aer documentation.
